# Swtching desktops using the mouse

Tags: mouse, virtualdesktop

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04. If the mouse wanders into the virtual desktop region, which can easily happen,  the mouse wheel switches me to different virtual desktops. This takes me away from whatever I was working on.  What setting should I use to disable this effect?

Comment: I am not sure, so this is a comment. (I don't use KDE much.) Right click on the desktop and select configure desktop. Click on mouse actions and then the minus sign removes the vertical scroll changing the desktops. Is that the feature you're hoping to get rid of?

Comment: That seems to work, but time will tell.

Comment: I'm pretty sure (not 100%) that that's the solution and that it should stay gone once you've removed it. I could write it up as an answer, but it's probably already been asked somewhere around here.